# Bootstrap верстка определенного вида

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как правильно сверстать примерно такую сетку на бутстрапе?
[image: сетка]

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как его суть выражена картинкой, а не словами, что делает его бесполезным для базы знаний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.black {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200px;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 blue">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 red">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 black">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 green">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот так можешь попробовать, если нужны отступы внутренние `.row` убери

[Codepen-еще залил](http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/KgOBEY)